# 3 DIVs next to each other with middle filling the void

Tags: html, css, positioning

Hello I would like to ask you how to put 3 DIV next to each other while middle one is filling the void between first and third DIV.

I would like to to have dynamic buttons in first nad third DIV and I need the middle DIV to fill the space between DIV one and three.

I would brefer pure CSS / HTML (no JavaScript)

Here is my try:

http://jsfiddle.net/4smx3627/

```
#wrapper{
height: 30px;
}

#first{
    height: 100%;
    background-color:red;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

#second{
    height: 100%;
    background-color:green;
    display: inline-block;
}

#third{
    height: 100%;
    background-color:yellow;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Thank you very much for any advice.

Comment: Have you gave it a try? Can you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: Yes i did try but this is all I could came up with http://jsfiddle.net/4smx3627/

Comment: do it as a table...with each div as a `table-cell` and give the edge ones width of `1%`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this. A modern way which most accurately reflects your description is "Flexbox", however you may need to be careful of browser support. If you're only interested in the latest browser versions, it's a good option. Here's an example

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sxx65mhq/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div>first</div>
    <div class="middle">second</div>
    <div>third</div>
</div>
```

And CSS

```
.container {
    display: flex;
}

.middle {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

For browser support, see http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to float left and right. But pay attention to the order in the HTML. Floats are first then the middle div.

[JS Bin Here](http://jsbin.com/mefora/5/edit)

```
body{
  margin:0 auto;
}
div{
 margin:0 auto;
  border:0px solid;
 height:200px;
  display:block;
}
#one {
  width:20%;
  float:left;
}

#two {
  width:60%;


}

#three {
  width:20%;
  float:right;
}
```

Edit: changed borders to background colors for easier viewing of divs.

Comment: Probably better to specify absolute widths on `#one` and `#three` and no width at all on `#two`, e.g. http://jsbin.com/solonadimame/1/edit

Comment: That's for the OP to decide. OP's question was vague. Let them make adjustments as needed.

Comment: I was just trying to be helpful - the question says "the middle DIV to fill the space", which to me strongly suggests the other divs should not expand to fill the space.

Comment: True... what sucks about being the first to answer is when they add more to the question afterwards. I see there is even a Fiddle up there now too.